# How to make a clean time series from a dataset that has approx 200 countries?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

This is the dataset I am working with (text version below):
[image]

I am trying to make a time series plot that shows a country's performance over time. I used pandas to add new columns, for home points or away points, for each match. I then see each country's total points per year to measure performance over time and make a time series plot from the points per year. However, the issue is the dataset has matches for around 200 countries since 1872. As a result, my time series looks like this:
[image]

I have tried using `df.resample` and resampling the dataframe to show 10 year periods, but that is not working and the time series looks cluttered. Does anyone have any recommendations for how I can make this time series clean in order to show a country's performance over time?

Text version of data:

```
date    home_team   away_team   home_score  away_score  tournament  city    country neutral total_goals points_home points_away
0   1872-11-30  Scotland    England 0   0   Friendly    Glasgow Scotland    False   0   1.0 1.0
1   1873-03-08  England Scotland    4   2   Friendly    London  England False   6   3.0 0.0
2   1874-03-07  Scotland    England 2   1   Friendly    Glasgow Scotland    False   3   3.0 0.0
3   1875-03-06  England Scotland    2   2   Friendly    London  England False   4   1.0 1.0
4   1876-03-04  Scotland    England 3   0   Friendly    Glasgow Scotland    False   3   3.0 0.0
5   1876-03-25  Scotland    Wales   4   0   Friendly    Glasgow Scotland    False   4   3.0 0.0
6   1877-03-03  England Scotland    1   3   Friendly    London  England False   4   0.0 3.0
```

Comment: It's not possible to plot 200 countries and have a clean plot. You have some options, like selecting some countries and graying out the rest. Or Only plotting the selected countries. But 200 lines will always be cluttered.

Comment: would it be a good idea to separate by continent? Since I am trying to see which country's performance degraded the most over time?

Comment: If I were you I would create a measurement of "degradation" and then plot bars of that measure for each country. If you're interested in which countries are more degraded, plot the top 20 or so countries, so you can easily see individual countries. In this way your plots at least won't be mixed.

Comment: thanks for the advice!

Comment: You're very welcome !